# Does variation in points allocated to questions score affect whether it is interval or ordinal data

Tags: dataset, ordinal-data

I have a test that has 12 questions: the first three are 2 point questions and the other 9 are 1 point questions. The students can score a 0,1, or 2 on the two point questions. Does the fact that there are different scores per question change the data to ordinal data, since there is no longer a direct mapping between number of questions correct and the number of points they receive?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Since the data is still quantifiable with a specific range of scores, the data is still interval.